# Is there anything wrong with using an object as a constant?

Tags: perl

I'm using a `WWW::Mechanize` object as a constant, and it's working well for me, but it feels kinda weird.

```
use constant MECH => WWW::Mechanize->new(agent => 'my_app');
```

Is there anything "wrong" with using an object as a constant?

Answer (score 3):

It's basically fine, but it is only the *reference* that is constant. I often use constant URLs, like this

```
use constant URL => URI->new('http://www.example.com/');
```

But if you're actually modifying the object then it may get a little confusing. I clone from constants to create a similar value, like

```
my $url = URL->clone->path('/path/to/resource');
```

and `WWW::Mechanize` also has a `clone` method if you wish to use a similar approach. I don't think it's appropriate to use it as a variable, for instance

```
MECH->get($url);
```

and I don't see why you would want to

Answer (score 2):

No, not inherently wrong.

A Perl constant is just an inlinable subroutine that has an empty prototype. In the example you provided you can look at `MECH` as an accessor to an instance of the `WWW::Mechanize` class.  The same instance will be shared with any consumer of the `MECH` constant.

This:

```
use constant MECH => WWW::Mechanize->new(agent => 'my_app');
```

...is roughly equivalent to the following snippet:

```
BEGIN {
    my $mech;
    sub MECH() {
        return $mech //= WWW::Mechanize->new(agent => 'my_app');
    }
}
```

Or, using a `state` variable:

```
sub MECH() {
    state $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(agent => 'my_app');
    return $mech;
}
```

Comment: No, it's actually close to `BEGIN { my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(agent => 'my_app'); sub MECH() { $mech } }`. Initialization isn't deferred.

Comment: yes in other applications for this purpose I've used a singleton (utilizing `state` obviously). basically I'm  working though different ways to make global variables elegant :P

Answer (score -1):

My advice is not to do it. The one thing so-called constants defined using `use constant` in Perl are good for is to enable constant-folding. For example, when you say `use constant N_CONNECTIONS => 5`, everywhere `perl` sees `N_CONNECTIONS`, it is replaced with `5` at *compile time* making further optimizations possible.

```
$perl -MO=Deparse -e 'use constant X => 17; if ( X < 5 ) { rand }'
use constant ('X', 17);
'???';
-e syntax OK
```

See, a whole bunch of code just got pruned. Or,

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'use constant X => 17; $x = X'
use constant ('X', 17);
$x = 17;
-e syntax OK
```

`perl` knew to assign the literal `17` to `$x` at compile time.

Let's see what your construct evaluates to:

```
$ perl -MWWW::Mechanize -MO=Deparse -e 'use constant MECH => WWW::Mechanize->new(agent => "my_app"); $x = MECH'
use constant ('MECH', 'WWW::Mechanize'->new('agent', 'my_app'));
$x = {autocheck => 1, cookie_jar => {COOKIES => {}}, current_form => undef, def_headers => {user-agent => 'my_app'}, forms => undef, handlers => {request_prepare => [{callback => sub {
    package LWP::UserAgent;
    use strict;
    $jar->add_cookie_header($_[0]);
}
, line => '/Users/.../opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm:755', owner => 'LWP::UserAgent::cookie_jar'}], response_done => [{callback => sub {
    package LWP::UserAgent;
    use strict;
    $jar->extract_cookies($_[0]);
}
, line => '/Users/.../opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm:758', owner => 'LWP::UserAgent::cookie_jar'}], response_header => [{callback => sub {
    package LWP::UserAgent;
    use strict;
    my($response, $ua) = @_;
    require HTML::HeadParser;
    $parser = 'HTML::HeadParser'->new;
    $parser->xml_mode(1) if $response->content_is_xhtml;
    $parser->utf8_mode(1) if $] >= 5.008 and $HTML::Parser::VERSION >= 3.4;
    push @{$$response{'handlers'}{'response_data'};}, {'callback', sub {
        return unless $parser;
        unless ($parser->parse($_[3])) {
            my $h = $parser->header;
            my $r = $_[0];
            foreach my $f ($h->header_field_names) {
                $r->init_header($f, [$h->header($f)]);
            }
            undef $parser;
        }
    }
    };
}
, line => '/Users/.../opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm:734', m_media_type => 'html', owner => 'LWP::UserAgent::parse_head'}]}, headers => {}, images => undef, links => undef, local_address => undef, max_redirect => 7, max_size => undef, no_proxy => [()], noproxy => 0, onerror => sub {
    package WWW::Mechanize;
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    require Carp;
    return &Carp::croak;
}
, onwarn => sub {
    package WWW::Mechanize;
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    require Carp;
    return &Carp::carp;
}
, page_stack => [()], protocols_allowed => undef, protocols_forbidden => undef, proxy => {}, quiet => 0, requests_redirectable => ['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST'], show_progress => undef, ssl_opts => {verify_hostname => 1}, stack_depth => 8675309, text => undef, timeout => 180, title => undef, use_eval => 1};
-e syntax OK
```

So, everywhere you use `MECH`, it will be replaced with this gnarly thing at compile time.

Sure, things will work, but would you write something like this on purpose?

Since `MECH` is now a subroutine in your package, it can be invoked by code from the outside. It may not matter to you, but it does break encapsulation.

Now, we come to my other problem. An instance of `WWW::Mechanize` is not a constant, really. Every time you call methods on it, its internal state changes. So, using constant to refer to something that is in a state seems incongruous at best.

It looks like you are trying to avoid having to pass `$mech` to a bunch of subroutines. This is a good point to encapsulate your specific crawler in a class and give it a `mech` class member. Then, the methods in your class can refer to it as `$self->mech` and you don't need to pass it around.

But, ultimately, you asked a subjective question. I have tried to explain why I this is a good idea. Using globals is a bad idea in general.

Go ahead and use it if you don't agree with me.

Comment: I'm aware of the compile time behavior but strictly speaking, why does it matter that it's "gnarly"? is it anything more than inelegance?

Comment: as for encapsulation, I don't think it's a concern for me here because the constant isn't being used in a module.

Comment: @beasy Your question was originally tagged `OOP` which is why I appealed to concepts such as encapsulation. I have since removed that tag, since you have clarified such concerns do not apply.